# Allow a UIBarButtonItem to touch top & bottom of UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Take a look at the Droplr iPhone app:

[image]

Notice how the `UIBarButtonItem`s are able to touch the right, left, top, and bottom of the screen/navigation bar?

How can I achieve something similar?  Here's how I make a sample UIBarButton and set it to the right item:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
button.frame= CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *bb = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button]autorelease];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:bb animated:YES];
```

However, it is **not** right aligned, and has quite a bit of margin from the top & the bottom.  My image size is correct (44px), and it looks like it shrinks it to fit a frame of sorts.

So, how can I do this?

---

**Edit:** Whoops, the top/bottom spacing was my fault. However, I can't figure out how to align the bar button flush with the left/right side.  Here's what I mean: (sorry for the ugly button, it was just a test)

[image]

I tried setting the image inserts, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIView *rightview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];



UIButton *searchbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,2,50, 30)];
[searchbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some-pic.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[rightview addSubview:searchbutton];


UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightview];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];
```

I use a customView for the rightBarButtonItem and I get it right aligned.
Just try a bit with the CGRectMake-Numbers for the x-coordinate, for testing I added to high numbers...

Comment: So, essentially you nest views, and displace the inner view to 'offset' the margin. The containing view must be set to clipsToBounds=NO, but I guess that is the default?

Comment: This technique works also to overcome the 'maximum imposed width' of the title view: I found that, when both left and right items are present, the title view is constrained to 132 points wide. Using an image view inside a view fixed it.

Comment: clipsToBounds is not a property of UIBarButtonItem or it's superclass UIBarItem. It's only available on UIView